# zscale is not recognized

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

I am trying to draw my own 3d shapes in tikz. Arguments "xscale" and "yscale" work as expected; however, apparently there is no "zscale". Is there any quick fix to this?

Thank you.

Edit: For more context let's say I want to draw a cuboid and be able to scale it on the zaxis (x, and y axis works.) My attempt is the following. How should I change it to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[7]{% width, height, depth, scale, scale x ->, scale y |, scale z/
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = #4, xscale = #5, yscale = #6, zscale= #7]
        \begin{scope}[thick, dashed]
            %x strokes
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                    \draw (0, \y, \z) -- (#1, \y, \z);
            %y strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                    \draw (\x, 0, \z) -- (\x, #2, \z);
            %z strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                    \draw (\x, \y, 0) -- (\x, \y, #3);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[very thick]
            %x strokes
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \draw (0, \y, #3) -- (#1, \y, #3);
            \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                \draw (0, #2, \z) -- (#1, #2, \z);
            %y strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \draw (\x, 0, #3) -- (\x, #2, #3);
            \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                \draw (#1, 0, \z) -- (#1, #2, \z);
            %z strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \draw (\x, #2, 0) -- (\x, #2, #3);
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \draw (#1, \y, 0) -- (#1, \y, #3);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \tikzcuboid{2}{2}{2}{1}{1}{1}{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because TikZ is 2 dimensional. Asymptote is 3 dimensional. It is better to post the figure you want to draw. In some simple case, TikZ can draw 3D-like figures

Comment: @BlackMild I have updated my answer. Hope that you could help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: from your code, it seems that what you need is not `zscale` (of the unit cube for example), but just changing the view of the object, isn't it?

Comment: @BlackMild well, I am not sure what you mean exactly. I want to stretch the cube from z axis. The answer does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default unit vector for the z-direction is (-3.85mm, -3,85mm), so perhaps you can scale that. I.e., `z={(#7*-3.85mm, #7*-3.85mm)}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[7]{% width, height, depth, scale, scale x ->, scale y |, scale z/
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = #4, xscale = #5, yscale = #6, z={(#7*-3.85mm, #7*-3.85mm)}]
        \begin{scope}[thick, dashed]
            %x strokes
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                    \draw (0, \y, \z) -- (#1, \y, \z);
            %y strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                    \draw (\x, 0, \z) -- (\x, #2, \z);
            %z strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                    \draw (\x, \y, 0) -- (\x, \y, #3);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[very thick]
            %x strokes
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \draw (0, \y, #3) -- (#1, \y, #3);
            \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                \draw (0, #2, \z) -- (#1, #2, \z);
            %y strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \draw (\x, 0, #3) -- (\x, #2, #3);
            \foreach \z in {0, ..., #3}
                \draw (#1, 0, \z) -- (#1, #2, \z);
            %z strokes
            \foreach \x in {0, ..., #1}
                \draw (\x, #2, 0) -- (\x, #2, #3);
            \foreach \y in {0, ..., #2}
                \draw (#1, \y, 0) -- (#1, \y, #3);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \tikzcuboid{2}{2}{2}{1}{1}{1}{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

3D with Asymptote has different flavor that I feel more realistic. Once  [three](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/three.html#three) module is imported, it give us 3 linearly independent coordinates: `X=(1,0,0)`, `Y=(0,1,0)`, and `Z=(0,0,1)`. We can choose viewpoint as orthogonal or perspective projection. Moreover, scaling is intuitive

`xscale3(real x)` scales by x in the x direction;

`yscale3(real y)` scales by y in the y direction;

`zscale3(real z)` scales by z in the z direction;

`scale3(real s)` scales by s in the x, y, and z directions;

`scale(real x, real y, real z)` scales by x in the x direction, by y in the y direction, and by z in the z direction;

In your situation (I don't see any scaling!), copy the following code to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click Run to see the result (then freely rotate the figure by mouse)

[image]

```
import three;
unitsize(3cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(2,1,1,zoom=.9,center=true);

draw(O--X--X+Y--Y--cycle^^Z--X+Z--X+Y+Z--Y+Z--cycle^^
O--Z^^X--X+Z^^X+Y--X+Y+Z^^Y--Y+Z);

path3 s1=.5X--.5X+Y--.5X+Y+Z--.5X+Z--cycle;
draw(s1^^.5X+.5Y--.5X+.5Y+Z,red);

path3 s2=.5Y--.5Y+X--.5Y+X+Z--.5Y+Z--cycle;
draw(s2^^.5Y+.5Z--X+.5Y+.5Z,green);

path3 s3=X+.5Z--X+.5Z+Y--.5Z+Y--.5Z--cycle;
draw(s3^^.5X+.5Z--.5X+.5Z+Y,blue);

//draw(surface(s1),red+opacity(.5));
//draw(surface(s2),green+opacity(.5));
//draw(surface(s3),blue+opacity(.5));

//draw(unitcube,yellow+opacity(.5));
```

If you like using dashed lines for expressing hidden lines, then it is straightforward  by hand when projection is fixed.

[image]

```
import three;
size(8cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(2,1,1,zoom=.9,center=true);

draw(X--X+Y--Y^^Z--X+Z--X+Y+Z--Y+Z--cycle^^
X--X+Z^^X+Y--X+Y+Z^^Y--Y+Z);
draw(O--X^^O--Y^^O--Z,dashed);

draw(.5X+Z--.5X+Z+Y--.5X+Y,red);
draw(.5X+Z--.5X--.5X+Y^^.5X+.5Z--.5X+.5Z+Y,red+dashed);

draw(X+.5Z--X+.5Z+Y--.5Z+Y,orange);
draw(X+.5Z--.5Z--.5Z+Y^^.5Y+.5Z--X+.5Y+.5Z,orange+dashed);

draw(.5Y+Z--X+.5Y+Z--X+.5Y,blue);
draw(.5Y+Z--.5Y--X+.5Y^^.5X+.5Y--.5X+.5Y+Z,blue+dashed);
```

Personally, instead of dashed line, I like to use `opacity(.5)` to make object transparent in order to see hidden lines or curve.

```
draw(surface(s1),red+opacity(.5));
draw(surface(s2),green+opacity(.5));
draw(surface(s3),blue+opacity(.5));
```

check `pdf` to download, then open in Acrobat, you will see

[image]