scale the x y and z dimensions individually in tikz-3dplot
In regular tikz, there are the xscale and yscale options. These only work on the screen image's dimensions though.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]
    \foreach \level in {0,...,10}{
        \draw (0.1*\level,0) circle[x radius=1, y radius=2];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I use tikz-3dplot, and would like to be able to scale the x y and z dimensions individually. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600107/319072 only provides a workaround for the typical z unit vector - which changes when we use \tdplotsetmaincoords{}{} and [tdplot_main_coords].
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \foreach \level in {0,...,10}{
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\level] (0,0) circle[x radius=1, y radius=2];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



tikz-3dplot set tdplot_main_coords with
\tikzset{tdplot_main_coords/.style={x={(\raarot cm,\rbarot cm)},y={(\rabrot cm, \rbbrot cm)},z={(\racrot cm, \rbcrot cm)}}}%

So you can define a derived style, scaled, with
\tikzset{tdplot_scaled_coords/.style n args={3}{x={(#1*\raarot cm,#1*\rbarot cm)},y={(#2*\rabrot cm, #2*\rbbrot cm)},z={(#3*\racrot cm, #3*\rbcrot cm)}}}%

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\tikzset{tdplot_scaled_coords/.style n args={3}{x={(#1*\raarot cm,#1*\rbarot cm)},y={(#2*\rabrot cm, #2*\rbbrot cm)},z={(#3*\racrot cm, #3*\rbcrot cm)}}}%

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    tdplot_main_coords,
  ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    tdplot_scaled_coords={1}{2}{3},
  ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


